# How to change the font color of Header and Footer Text (which is merge field) and exist Line color change in Aspose Word Java

Tags: java, aspose.words

I have an existing Aspose word template, I want to change the font color of the text in header and footer which is merge field value.

Also, I have exist line (shape), I want to change the color of this line.
How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Color of text can be changed using Run.Font.Color property. You can get Run nodes in any headers/footers and change text color using the following code:

```
HeaderFooter primaryHeader = doc.getFirstSection().getHeadersFooters().
        getByHeaderFooterType(HeaderFooterType.HEADER_PRIMARY);
for (Run run : (Iterable<Run>) primaryHeader.getChildNodes(NodeType.RUN, true)){
    run.getFont().setColor(Color.RED);
}
```

Using [Aspose.Words for Java](http://www.aspose.com/java/word-component.aspx), you can also change stroke color of Shape using the following code:

```
for (Shape shape : (Iterable<Shape>) doc.getChildNodes(NodeType.SHAPE, true)){
    shape.setStrokeColor(Color.RED);
}
```

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.